# Nextjs How to opt out of build time static optimization for a single route without opting out of caching?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Using nextjs 13 with App router.
To use runtime variables on the client I am using a server function in `layout.tsx` to read the `process.env` and pass them as data. There isn't any data fetching (fetch calls), or calling of route handlers needed to do this as it's happening on the server, so `process.env` is the runtime process.

I can force `layout.tsx` to be dynamic using invalidation strategies eg. `const dynamic` or adding a no-cache fetch call but that's different to what I'd like to achieve.

It seems the only way to opt-out of the pre-render build time is to disable caching.

When building this will be statically optimized so the `process` will be the Node build time process. There are no blocking requirements, so it will render at build time. The variables should be cached and called once because they won't change, but I don't want them pre-rendered at build time.

```js
async function getConfig() {
  if (process.env.NEXT_IS_BUILDING === "true") {
    console.log(
      "app config runtime values not available on build process node env
    );
  } else {
    const config = process.env; // this should be server side runtime process
    return config;
  }
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const appConfig = await getConfig();
  console.log("render Rootlayout app config", appConfig);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <pre>{appConfig}</pre>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```